# Why do changes to a temporary variable representing a row of a matrix, affect the row of the matrix itself?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to write a code that can do elementary row operations on matrices and I have run into some issues. I realize that there are libraries that have functions that can be used to complete these operations; however, I am doing this for my own gratification.

The problem arises with the replacement operation. The intended purpose of this operation is to replace a row by the sum of itself and the multiple of another row.  For example, if I have a matrix [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1]] , I want to replace the top row (the row [1,2,3]) with the sum of itself and the second row (the row [2,1,3]) multiplied by a factor of 2. I would like the code to give me: [[5,4,9],[2,1,3],[3,2,1]]

When I enter this particular matrix, the answer I get is: [[5, 4, 9], [4, 2, 6], [3, 2, 1]]

My code is as follows:

```
def multiply_row(matrix,row_num,factor):
    #Let row_num = 1 indicate the top row
    temp_row = matrix[row_num - 1]
    entries = len(matrix[row_num - 1])
    current_term = 0
    while current_term < entries:
        temp_row[current_term] = temp_row[current_term] * factor  
        current_term = current_term + 1    
    return temp_row

def replacement(matrix,rowA,rowB,factor):
    #Replace 1 row be by the sum of itself and a multiple of another row
    #rowA is the row being replaced
    #rowB is being multiplied by the factor
    #Let rowA = 1 indicate the top row
    temp_rowB = multiply_row(matrix,rowB,factor)
    entries = len(matrix[rowA - 1])
    current_term = 0
    while current_term < entries:
        matrix[rowA - 1][current_term] = temp_rowB[current_term] + matrix[rowA - 1][current_term]
        current_term = current_term + 1
    return matrix

m = [
    [1,2,3],
    [2,1,3],
    [3,2,1]
    ]

print replacement(m, 1, 2, 2)
```

Clearly, the problem lies within my “multiply_row” function. I created this function so that I could create a temporary place where I can multiply a row by  a factor, without actually affecting the row in the matrix itself. This is not working.

I was wondering if someone could explain why this temporary row is actually altering the row in the matrix itself. Also, I realize that I am probably not doing the operation in the most efficient way possible and I would be curious to know what the more efficient way to do it would be (this is only secondary, I would really appreciate an answer to my first question).

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `temp_row` is not a *copy* of the row in your matrix but a *reference* to it. Anything you do to `temp_row` therefore happens to the corresponding row in your matrix, since it is happening to the same object (which happens to be referenced in two different ways). Replace the line in `multiply_row()` with

```
temp_row = matrix[row_num - 1][:]
```

to make a copy. You then get:

```
[[5, 4, 9], [2, 1, 3], [3, 2, 1]]
```

as you required.